# Plone 4.1 Windows Installer Changes

Tags: windows, plone

I have just installed setup-plone41-4.1.0-5091-win32.exe from Plone.org. There are many changes from Plone 4.0.x Windows installer, including the disappearance of Plone Controller and ZEO automatically installing via buildout.

I understand how to start/stop Plone from the command line, so Plone Controller's disappearance is only a minor inconvenience. But I am flailing around with understanding the ZEO install. I have searched here on Stack Overflow, Google, Plone.org, the issue tracker and Enfold Systems' website but cannot find any documentation for this new Windows installer. The only documentation provided in the install itself is a commercial for Enfold Proxy (for which I am already a customer).

Where can I find out more information on the new Windows installer and the changes that have been made? Is Plone Controller gone for good? Why is ZEO now part of the default install?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the new Windows Plone Installer documentation here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/19-o6yYJWuvw7eyUiLs_b8br4C-Kb8RcyHcQSIf_4Pb4/edit?hl=en_US

Once you have the services installed you can stop/start them from the services interface under Computer Management (you don't have to run them from the command line).